# How does `return` statement have different type than that of a function's definition?

Tags: haskell, types, type-inference, io-monad, do-notation

Within a loop, integers are collected inside a list, and a tuple of these integers is `return`ed. How does this change to a list of tuples?

```
input :: IO [(Int,Int)]
input = do
  n <- readLn :: IO Int
  forM [1..n] $ \_ -> do
    [x,y] <- map read . words <$> getLine
    return (x,y)
```

I expected type of value to be `(Int,Int)` but it is `[(Int,Int)]`. Why?

Comment: what exactly is your question? It's really not clear to me what you're asking

Comment: There is no "return statement". `return` is a function (and a virtual constructor).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's re-write your code with explicit separators making the code structure more self-apparent:

```
input :: IO [(Int,Int)]
input = do {
    n <- readLn ;
    forM [1..n] (\ _ -> do {
        [x,y] <- fmap (map read . words) getLine ;
        return (x,y)  })
    }
```

so `return (x,y)` belongs to the internal `do`.

Since there's a `getLine :: IO String` there, the internal `do`'s type is `IO (t1,t2)` where `x :: t1, y :: t2`. So this is also the return type of *that lambda function* participating in that `forM` call.

Since `forM :: Monad m => [a] -> (a -> m b) -> m [b]`, and we know `m ~ IO` here, we get the type of the overall `do`'s last expression as

```
forM :: [a] -> (a -> IO b) -> IO [b]
```

and thus the overall type is `IO [b] ~ IO [(t1,t2)]` since `b ~ (t1,t2)` as per that `return` expression.

The lambda function returns `IO b` so `forM` returns `IO [b]` as per its type above. And the type of `do` block is the same as the type of its last expression.

The function's signature says it's `IO [(Int,Int)]`, so finally `t1 ~ Int` and `t2 ~ Int` and everything fits.